# warning C6236: ( || ) is always a non-zero constant

Tags: c++, visual-studio, if-statement

I have an if statement that seems to simply be not working. I am certain this is a stupid error, but I can't figure it out.

```
void convertTemp()
{
    char choice;
    float userTemp;
    cout << "Input either F or C followed by a temperature and this program will convert it to the opposite." << endl;
    cout << "Example: (F 260.8)" << endl;
    cout << "Input: ";
    cin >> choice; choice = toupper(choice); //Read in and convert user letter to capital 
    cin >> userTemp;

    if (choice != 'F' || 'C')
    {
        cout << "Invalid format. Check your letter and temperature" << endl;
        system("pause");
        return;
    }
```

this simple if statement is meant to check if the users character input is NOT 'F' or 'C', and then return an error message and kick them out of the function. However, this if statement always returns true regardless of input, and I can't figure out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Visual studio is giving me this warning message. I read about the error code, but I am having a tough time understanding it.

> warning C6236: ( || ) is always a non-zero constant

Comment: `if (choice != 'F' || 'C')` -- This does not do what you think it does.  In the C++ book you're using, how do they show how compound statements are done in `if` clauses?  If you're not using a book, C++ is not the type of language where guessing will help.

Comment: The reason is `'C'` is always true. You are not comparing it to `choice`.

Comment: There are a few languages where the compound `if` statements are stated in the way we speak shorthand English, i.e. `if choice is 'F' or 'C'...`, however C++ is not one of them.  You have to explicitly state each portion of the compound condition completely.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie heard that! Thank you for helping me fix this error!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `if` statements need to be explicit, `if (choice != 'F' || 'C')` will not work.

The correct `if` statement is `if (choice != 'F' && choice != 'C')`.

Edit: As for an explanation, the `||` means you have two statements being evaluated. In English, the statement can be read as:

`IF the choice is not 'F' or IF 'C'`

...and that doesn't really make sense. You need to explicitly state that you want both sides to evaluate if choice is equal to the values.

Thanks to Pete Becker as well, I copied and pasted your issue without actually digging into the logic behind what you were doing. If you are attempting to use an `OR` with `!=`, one half will pretty much always evaluate to true. Using `&&` is the operator you want so you can check if `choice` is not `C` or `F`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The issue here was that I was only running one comparison in my IF statement. 
(**choice != 'F'** || 'C'). The bold comparison was being ran, but 'C' wasn't being compared to anything.

The fix is run 2 comparisons as demonstrated here. 
**(choice != 'F' && choice != 'C')**. I am now comparing choice to 'F' and 'C' separately.